# Python Requests Not Respecting verify=False

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

Python requests is giving me an ssl handshake failure even when verify=False (I know that not using SSL is inadvisable). Requests works as expected for me with other sites that have valid certs. I'm using 2.7.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv

outputfile  = open('/Users/jim/Documents/FabFoundationURLs.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

source = 'https://www.fablabs.io/labs'

page = requests.get(source, verify=False)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of links:
links = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]//span/a/text()')

targets = links

print links
```

Here's the exception:

```
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: you forgot to include the exact exception you get.

Comment: Sorry! It's up there now.

Answer (score 0):

SSL handshake error can be a protocol error instead of a cert verification error.  In this case it happens before the cert verification: you can't establish the SSL connection and verify=False won't help.  Protocol error generally refers to an unknown/unistalled SSL cipher version.

You can try to reinstall extra ciphers in requests (worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04, but not on OS X)

```
pip install requests[security]
```

Answer (score 0):

A coworker ran into this issue running MacOS Ventura.

Turned out, Requests was using `Urllib3 2.0.3`
However, her Mac was using `LibreSSL 3.3.6`

The [UrlLib 2 Migration guide](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v2-migration-guide.html) states:
**Removed support for non-OpenSSL TLS libraries (like LibreSSL and wolfSSL).**

So we installed `UrlLib3 1.26`

```
pip3 install urllib3=1.26
```

After restarting the IDE for the Lib change to get picked up, it worked.

I'm sure someone can give better pip syntax to get the latest 1.x version.